# Drag feature in HTML 5 paint application

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, paint

I created simple paint application using html 5 canvas and java script. I want add drag feature to my app. ie circle can be drag from one place to another like we see in ms paint.

what all changes are need to be done in my code in order to drag feature work. please help.

my code given below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Paint</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #paintbg {
    background-color: #333333;
  }
  #realCanvas, #tempCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    left:350px;
    top:55px;
    border: 5px double gray;
    cursor: crosshair;
  }
  #toolset {
   width: 80px; 
   position: absolute;
   left:240px;
   top:50px; 
   background:#35d128; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   }
   #colorset{
     background:#aaaaaa; 
     position: absolute;
     left:350px;
     top:520px; 
     border:1px solid #888888;
   }
   #tools{
     background:#358128; 
     color:#f3f3f3;
     width:80px;
     height:25px;
     border:1px solid #33842a;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
     box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
    }
    #tools:hover{
      color:#edebda;
      -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 0 1px 0px;
      -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 0 1px 0px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 0 1px 0px;
    }
    #tools:active{
      background:#014400; 
      width:75px
    }

</style>
</head>
<body id="paintbg">
  <form>
  <fieldset id="toolset">

    <br><button id="tools" type="button" onclick="curr_tool('circle')">Circle</button></br>
    <br><button id="tools" type="button" onclick="clears()">Clear</button></br>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div>
    <canvas id="realCanvas" width="700" height="450" style=" background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 0"  ></canvas>
    <canvas id="tempCanvas" width="700" height="450"  style="z-index: 1"></canvas>
  </div>  
  <fieldset id="colorset">
  <table >
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="fill"/>Fill</td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#000000')" style="background-color: #000000; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#ff0000')" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#ff7f00')" style="background-color: #ff7f00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#ffff00')" style="background-color: #ffff00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#ffffff')" style="background-color: #ffffff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#00ff00')" style="background-color: #00ff00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#008800')" style="background-color: #008800; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#00ffff')" style="background-color: #00ffff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#0000ff')" style="background-color: #0000ff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="fillcolor('#8b00ff')" style="background-color: #8b00ff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="outline" checked="checked"/>Outline</td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#000000')" style="background-color: #000000; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#ff0000')" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#ff7f00')" style="background-color: #ff7f00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#ffff00')" style="background-color: #ffff00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#ffffff')" style="background-color: #ffffff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#00ff00')" style="background-color: #00ff00; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#008800')" style="background-color: #008800; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#00ffff')" style="background-color: #00ffff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#0000ff')" style="background-color: #0000ff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="linecolor('#8b00ff')" style="background-color: #8b00ff; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></button></td>

  </table>
  </fieldset>
 <script>
  var board = document.getElementById("realCanvas");
  var tmp_board = document.getElementById("tempCanvas");
  b_width = board.width;
  b_height = board.height;
  var ctx = board.getContext("2d");
  var tmp_ctx = tmp_board.getContext("2d");
  var x ;
  var y ;
  var hold = false;
  var fill = false;
  var stroke = true;
  var tool = 'pencil';
  tmp_ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  tmp_ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  function curr_tool(selected){tool = selected;}
  function attributes(){
    if (document.getElementById("fill").checked)
      fill = true;
    else
      fill = false;
    if (document.getElementById("outline").checked)
      stroke = true;
    else
      stroke = false;
  }

  function clears(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, b_width, b_height);
  }
  function linecolor(scolor){  
    if (document.getElementById("outline").checked)
      tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = scolor;
  }
  function fillcolor(fcolor){
    if (document.getElementById("fill").checked)
      tmp_ctx.fillStyle =  fcolor;
  }
  tmp_board.onmousedown = function(e) {
        attributes();
        x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        y = e.pageY -this.offsetTop;
        hold = true;
        begin_x = x;
        begin_y = y;
        tmp_ctx.beginPath();
        tmp_ctx.moveTo(begin_x, begin_y);    
  }

  tmp_board.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (x == null || y == null) {
          return;
        }
        if(hold){

        x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        goDraw();
        }
      }

  tmp_board.onmouseup = function(e) {
        ctx.drawImage(tmp_board,0, 0);
        tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_board.width, tmp_board.height);
        x = null;
        y = null;
        hold = false;
  }




tmp_board.ondblclick=function(e) {
goDraws();


}


  function goDraw(){

    if (tool == 'circle'){             
      tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, b_width, b_height);
      tmp_ctx.beginPath();
      tmp_ctx.arc(begin_x, begin_y, Math.abs(y - begin_y), 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
      if(stroke) 
        tmp_ctx.stroke();
      if(fill) 
        tmp_ctx.fill();
    }

   }

    function goDraws(){
        tmp_ctx.beginPath();
        tmp_ctx.arc(begin_x, begin_y, 100, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
        tmp_ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        tmp_ctx.fill()


        ctx.drawImage(tmp_board,0, 0);
                tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_board.width, tmp_board.height);
                x = null;
                y = null;
                hold = false;

}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/M2sQK/

Without providing you with the code itself, here are the problems and steps I would look at to implement a move feature. You will have to fill in the gaps.

1. These are drawn shapes, and not objects. You will need to store the data for each circle as an object `{shape:'circle', x:0, y:0, radius:0}`.
2. Create a grab tool. Attach (or add to) listeners for mouse-move and mouse-down.
3. Each time the move action is started, the script will have to iterate though a collection/array of your shape/circle objects to find an object to grab (reverse-iterate the array and grab the first object that matches the check in #4).
4. To find the circle you are clicking on, you will need to include some sort of "collision detection" (for a circle, I would recommend checking to see if the mouse x/y is within the circles radius from the circles center.) `if(Math.sqrt((circles[i].x - mouse.x) * (circles[i].x - mouse.x) + (circles[i].y - mouse.y) * (circles[i].y - mouse.y)) < circles[i].radius)`
5. Update the active objects x,y and redraw all the other circles to the canvas as the active circle is being moved.

Here is one of my canvas experiments that uses similar iteration/detection. http://jsfiddle.net/4ACYq/ Lines are drawn when circles get within a certain radius of other circles.